# CodeConfig equivalent for tx:attribute-driven

Tags: nhibernate, spring.net

I'm using CodeConfig as opposed to XML files for Spring.NET using Fluent NHibernate to read/write to the database.

But for transaction management, I still want to use Spring's [Transaction] attribute on my service methods. In XML I would do

```
<tx:attribute-driven/>
```

I can get around this by handling the transaction myself like this

```
public WorkItem SaveWorkItem(WorkItem workItem)
{
    using (ITransaction tx = CurrentSession.BeginTransaction())
    {
        CurrentSession.SaveOrUpdate(workItem);
        tx.Commit();
    }
    return workItem;
}
```

But is there a CodeConfig-only way of allowing this using an attribute instead, like this:

```
[Transaction]
public WorkItem SaveWorkItem(WorkItem workItem)
{
    CurrentSession.SaveOrUpdate(workItem);
    return workItem;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you get it working with attribute?

Comment: I didn't I'm afraid (and it doesn't look like there's much activity going on in Spring.NET land any more, sadly). I think I ended up using NHibernate's transactions instead.

Comment: OK, I am thinking of defining custom transaction advice aspect.

Answer (score 0):

I have a spring code config example on github for the TransactionAttribute:
https://github.com/gergroen/spring-net-getting-started-guide/blob/master/Spring.Net.GettingStarted/Config/ConfigurationOne.cs